# htaccess rewrite url to replace get variable names

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So, I am guessing that this question is asked pretty regularly, but I haven't been able to find any answers which will help me out. What I am wanting to do, is to replace the address:

```
www.site.com/workspace?wid=11
```

With the address:

```
wwww.site.com/workspace/11
```

How would I go about rewriting the URL like this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /workspace\?wid=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ workspace/%1? [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^workspace/([^/]+)/?$ workspace?wid=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: The site itself was removed - Instead of www.site.com/workspace/11 it ended up as www.workspace/11

Comment: ..What url did you enter? This code is working fine on my apache server.

Comment: The page is responding with a 404 error, although it's not using my personal 404 page...